# Calling iterator.next() through a TreeSet [example from Thinking In Java]

Tags: java, iterator, treeset

Reading Containers in Depth chapter from the Thinking In Java book. Saw this example(modified from SortedMapDemo.java):

```
 TreeSet<String> sortedSet = new TreeSet<String>(); 
 Collections.addAll(sortedSet,
           "a b c d e f g h"
             .split(" "));
...
Iterator<String> it = sortedSet.iterator();
for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
  if(i == 3) low = it.next();
  if(i == 6) high = it.next();
  else it.next();
}
print(low);
print(high); //overridden
```

What baffles me is that while 'low' prints out "d", 'high' prints out "h", for which I think should be "g" instead.
If we're calling it.next() in each iteration, shouldn't the 7th iteration gives "g"??

Comment: It is starting from 0.

Comment: Yeah. That explains why low= "d", but not why, after three increments, high gets to be "h".

Comment: Have you tried running this code yourself?

Comment: because `it.next()` does not execute when `if(i != 3)`

Comment: I did. 'print(sortedSet)' prints out [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h].  'print(low)' and 'print(high)' gives "d" and "h"

Comment: Should have added "with a debugger"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an `if` followed by an `if/else`. So the iteration occurs twice when `i == 3`. Here is your original code re-written with braces and spacing for clarity:

```
if (i == 3) {
    low = it.next();
}

if (i == 6) {
    high = it.next();
} else {
    it.next();
}
```

This would give you expected results:

```
if(i == 3) low = it.next();
else if(i == 6) high = it.next();
else it.next();
```

Comment: Goddarnit Mr. Bruce Eckel(the author)! such a tricksy move.. Thank you Duncan!